# Two SQL queries in one with ActiveRecord, or in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

I'm currently using [ActiveRecord to paginate items](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) with:

```
def index
  params[:per_page] ||= 50
  @articles = Article.limit(params[:per_page]).offset(params[:page].to_i * params[:per_page].to_i)
  @articles_count = Article.count
end
```

...and it's working well.

However, I'm wondering it if is possible to do those two queries with a single one with ActiveRecord, or in pure SQL (such as with postgresql). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use a subquery, but that won't improve performance, because the DBMS will still execute 2 separate queries:

```
SELECT
  article.*,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article) AS count
FROM article
LIMIT x
OFFSET y
```

But with this you can't easily use ActiveRecord.

MySQL however has a built-in function for the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM article` thing. But it will do the same: It just executes a second query with `COUNT(*)`.

Your solution works fine.